# use wc -l after succesfuly executing other commands first

Tags: wc

from a file (/etc/services) i need to take out all services, exluding all double or more entries per service, exluding lines starting with '#', sort alfabetically and store to a file. After all this was succesful, i need to count the lines. Adn this is where i struggle: to apply the wc -l command...
so far i have:

```
cut -f 1 etc/services | sed ‘/^#/ d‘ | sort | uniq -u > uniqueservices.txt
```

Could you help me out?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
cut -f 1 /etc/services | grep -v -E '^[[:space:]]?#' | sort -u > uniqueservices.txt && wc -l uniqueservices.txt
```

Comment: Hi, 

the actuall task is this:

Count the lines in the file using a conditional command that is only executed if the previous combined commands are successful.

So i guess it has to be in command, or is this not psible?

Comment: Just add `&&` between the pipeline and `wc`.

Comment: Thanks GMaster and Kusalananda!